# Rendering combo boxes in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecellrenderer

I have a `JTable` where one column has a [row-unique list of items with a JComboBox editor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535992/for-one-column-of-a-jtable-how-do-i-put-a-unique-combo-box-editor-in-each-row) (There are no event listeners involved.) The problem is that the cells are not displaying JComboBoxes, but just as `JLabel`s of the underlying list's `toString`. I have a class that `implements TableModel` which on `isCellEditable` returns true for that column. Rhe cells do not respond to the mouse.

I have tried having `getColumnClass` return both `JComboBox` and the class of the underlying list, and in both cases I still just get the list's `toString`. I haven't made much headway in trying to make my own renderer because 1. The Oracle tutorial "How to Use Tables" is one of the most incomprehensible programming web pages ever written, and 2. I *strongly* suspect that I am "doing it wrong" since surely swing already knows how to render a `JComboBox` of `String`s. Doesn't it?

The desired behavior is that they appear to be `JComboBox`es and can be edited with the mouse. I sense I should be posting more details but I don't know what I should be posting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JComboBox` may be used as a cell [editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), but you want a similar appearance for the cell [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). Two alternative approaches for this are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17342917/230513):

- Add an arrow to a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.
- Use a `ComboBoxRenderer` that `extends JComboBox` and `implements TableCellRenderer`.

Comment: I attempted to use the method for adding an arrow and it doesn't seem to have had any effect. Furthermore, that doesn't seem to have anything to do with resolving the issue of not displaying a proper default value and not responding to the mouse.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach; I started from @aterai's working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844115/230513).

Comment: Could not repro problem on simpler example. Will work out what I'm doing wrong and then refer to [Putting JComboBox into JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457463/putting-jcombobox-into-jtable)

Comment: See also [*Examples that Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg).